# Exporting interpolation (IDW,OK,UK…) prediction from gstat in ASCII format

Tags: r, interpolation, ascii, gstat

I am trying to export an interpolation (IDW, OK, UK, etc.) prediction generated using the gstat function in the R package. Specifically, I would like to save the resulting map as an ASCII file format compatible with ArcGIS (i.e., .asc or Esri ASCII raster format). Despite attempting to use both the 'raster' and 'rgdal' libraries, I have been unsuccessful in achieving this goal. How can I accomplish this task?

```
library(raster)
library(gstat) 
library(sp)    
library(sf)



dem = read_stars("C:\\Users\\kanon\\Desktop\\code_R\\ArcGIS\\dembigzone.tif")

dem = st_warp(dem, crs = 32646, cellsize = 500)

# Assign the file path to a variable
file_path <- file.path("C:\\Users\\kanon\\Desktop\\code_R\\data\\datapreci1998.txt")

# Read the file into a data frame
data <- read.table(file_path, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")

data = st_as_sf(data, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

# transform the CRS to the target CRS, in this case 
#the Universal Transverse Mercator (UTM) zone 46 north
data_transformed <- st_transform(data, 32646)
data = data_transformed

#==============================perform IDW==================================

g = gstat(formula = preci ~ 1, data = data)
IDW = predict(g, dem)
IDW = IDW["var1.pred"]

b = seq(0,500, 1)
plot(IDW, breaks = b, col = hcl.colors(length(b)-1, "Spectral"), reset = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: What did you try and how did it fail? You should be able to convert the gstat prediction object to a raster with `terra::rast(IDW)` and then save it with the `terra::writeRaster` function. Which of these steps is failing for you? Note that ASCII Grid format (.asc) needs square pixels but a geoTIFF should also work everywhere, and without that restriction)

Comment: I've found a solution:
I convert it convert to Raster using this line.
r = as(IDW, "Raster")
and then I wrote the ASCII with writeRaster